# Android studio showing error in build.gradle file

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I had a working project and today when i set with it after almost 2 weeks its showing error in build.gradle file. I might have installed the android studio updates. Below is what i have in gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.shaon.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    // RecyclerView

    // CardView
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.3'

    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:+'
}
```

and the error i am getting in from Build tab is :

```
../../Users/xxx/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-25.2.0.aar/a15b23bb4246ae6c7bb03ff4cce6bf47/res/values/values.xml    
    error: resource android:attr/fontStyle not found.   
    error: resource android:attr/font not found.    
    error: resource android:attr/fontWeight not found.  
    error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.   
    error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
```

Also in the declaration on the line `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'` - its showing error:

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 28.0.0-alpha1, 26.0.0-alpha1, 25.2.0. Examples include com.android.support:collections:28.0.0-alpha1 and com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.0.0-alpha1 less... (Ctrl+F1) 
>   There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion).

How do i solve this?

Comment: Try "build->clean Project" and rebuild again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an actual version rather than a plus on

```
support:palette-v7:+'
```

Make sure that version matches the other v7 ones

Comment: Thanks, It worked. Just changed it to:  `compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:25.2.0'`